# is this the result of a partial image transfer?

Tags: http, amazon-s3, clojure, jpeg

I have code that generates thumbnails from JPEGs. It pulls an image from S3 and then generates the thumbs.

One in about every 3000 files ends up looking like this. It happens in batches. The high res looks like this and they're all resized down to low res. It does not fail on resize. I can go to my S3 bucket and see that the original file is indeed intact.

I had this code written in Ruby and ported it all over to clojure hoping it would just fix my issue but it's still happening.

What would result in a JPEG that looks like this?

[image]

I'm using standard image copying code like so

```
(with-open [in (clojure.java.io/input-stream uri)
                out (clojure.java.io/output-stream file)]
      (clojure.java.io/copy in out))
```

Would there be any way to detect the transfer didn't go well in clojure? Imagemagick? Any other command line tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it is one of 2 possible issues (you know your code, so you can probably rule one out quickly):

1. You are running out of memory.  If the whole batch of processing is happening at once, the first few are probably not being released until the whole process is completed.
2. You are running out of time.  You may be reaching your maximum execution time for the script.

Implementing some logging as the batches are processed could tell you when the issue happens and what the overall state is at that moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since it happens so infrequently, it's really tough to find these instances. I think scenario 1 is more likely than 2, but would having no RAM available affect a server's ability to grab a tmp file ?

Comment: Also... in the event the file was output like this... How could i detect it ?

Comment: Just to clarify...the initial download (without re-sizing) is when you get this?  Yes, running low on RAM could still cause that...it is saving the file in ram before writing to disk.  When you re-size I assume the thumbnail then also is only partially rendered.  Is your end goal to have both, or only the thumbnail?  If the end goal is thumbs only, maybe you can use Imagemagick (or similar) to check the bottom row of pixel data on the original for this particular shade of grey and flag just that file for manual review rather than completing the batch resize? That would add a lot of overhead.

Comment: yes initial download and subsequent resizes look like this.